# Error message upon opening Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, android, genymotion

I am using a Dell Inspiron 1525 running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.I am getting a problem in running the android emulator on genymotion. Genymotion suggested to run it through oracle VM Virtualbox. When I did the above it showed an error message:-

> Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Google Nexus 7 2013 - 5.1.0 - API 22 - 1200x1920.
>   VT-x is not available. (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX).

What is a possible solution to this?

Comment: How did you set up the VM in VirtualBox?

Answer (score 2):

Old processors doesn't support virtualization technologies. You should first check that your CPU is compatible by searching informations (vtx instructions) on it on [Intel website.](http://ark.intel.com/)

According to the model of your PC, some processors [should be compatible](http://www.techrepublic.com/forums/questions/dell-inspiron-1525-processor-with-virtualization/) but I think you need to enable the virtualization capabilities in your bios.

- reboot your computer
- enter in the bios
- look at the entry Virtualization under POST behaviour.